# JSF dynamic ui:include

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, menu

In my app I have tutor and student as roles of user. And I decide that main page for both will be the same. But menu will be different for tutors and users. I made to .xhtml page tutorMenu.xhtml and student.xhtml. And want in dependecy from role include menu. For whole page I use layout and just in every page change content "content part" in ui:composition.

In menu.xhtml

```
<h:body>
    <ui:composition>        
            <div class="menu_header">
                <h2>
                    <h:outputText value="#{msg['menu.title']}" />
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="menu_content">
                <с:if test="#{authenticationBean.user.role.roleId eq '2'}">
                    <ui:include src="/pages/content/body/student/studentMenu.xhtml"/>
                </с:if>

                <с:if test= "#{authenticationBean.user.role.roleId eq '1'}">
                    <ui:include src="/pages/content/body/tutor/tutorMenu.xhtml" />
                </с:if>
            </div>      
    </ui:composition>
```

I know that using jstl my be not better solution but I can't find other. What is the best decision of my problem?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense

Comment: @BalusC Do you think that using h:panelGroup rendered will be better in my case?

Comment: No. You'll end up with two includes instead of one as the `rendered` attribute is evaluated during view render time, not during view build time like as JSTL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jstl-tags in this case is perfectly fine, since Facelets has a corresponding tag handlers (that are processed in the time of view tree creation) for the jstl tags and handles them perfectly. In this case c:if could prevent processing (and adding the components located in the included xhtml file) of the ui:include which leads to reduced component tree and better performance of the form.
One downside of using this approach is that you cannot update these form parts using ajax, i.e. you change the user role and refresh the form using ajax, because the ui:include for the other role is not part of the view anymore. In such case you have to perform a full page refresh.